# Change page view with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've implemented "change page" in my one page application with Backbone.js. However, I'm not sure if my Router should contain so much business logic. Should I consider go with Marionette.js to implement such functionality and make my Router thin? Should I worry about destroying Backbone models and views attached to "previous" active page/view when I change it (in order to avoid memory leaks) or it's enough to empty html attached to those models/views.
Here is my Router:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'users(/:user_id)' : 'users',
        'dashboard' : 'dashboard'
    },
    dashboard: function() {
        App.ActiveView.destroy_view();
        App.ActiveViewModel.destroy();

        App.ActiveViewModel = new App.Models.Dashboard;
        App.ActiveViewModel.fetch().then(function(){
            App.ActiveView = new App.Views.Dash({model: App.ActiveViewModel });
            App.ActiveView.render();
        });
    },

    users: function(user_id) {
        App.ActiveView.destroy_view();
        App.ActiveViewModel.destroy();

        App.ActiveViewModel = new App.Models.User;
        App.ActiveViewModel.fetch().then(function() {
            App.ActiveView =  new App.Views.UsersView({model: App.ActiveViewModel});
            App.ActiveView.render();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

**Create an AbstractView**

Having an `AbstractView` declared and then extending your other application specific `View's` from `AbstractView` has many advantages. You always have a `View` where you can put all the common functionalities.

```
App.AbstractView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render : function() {
        App.ActiveView && App.ActiveView.destroy_view();
        // Instead of destroying model this way you can destroy 
        // it in the way mentioned in below destroy_view method.
        // Set current view as ActiveView
        App.ActiveView = this;
        this.renderView && this.renderView.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    // You can declare destroy_view() here
    // so that you don't have to add it in every view.
    destroy_view : function() {
        // do destroying stuff here
         this.model.destroy();
    }
});
```

Your `App.Views.UsersView` should extend from `AbstractView` and have `renderView` in place of `render` because `AbstractView's` render will make a call to `renderView`. From the `Router` you can call `render` the same way `App.ActiveView.render();`

```
App.Views.UsersView = AbstractView.extend({
    renderView : function() {
    }
    // rest of the view stuff
});

App.Views.Dash = AbstractView.extend({
    renderView : function() {
    }
    // rest of the view stuff
});
```

Router code would then change to :

```
 dashboard: function() {
        App.ActiveViewModel = new App.Models.Dashboard;
        App.ActiveViewModel.fetch().then(function(){
            new App.Views.Dash({model: App.ActiveViewModel }).render();
        });
    }
```